# Can trauma to a liver with mild fat accumulation result in death?

Tags: autopsy, fatty-liver-disease

Autopsy report of a person showed mild accumulation of fat in liver. Q1. Is mild accumulation of fat in liver common?
There was evidence of trauma to upper abdominal cavity. Q2. Can mild trauma to fatty liver be fatal. I know trauma to the liver in general can create complications, but is the fatty liver more vulnerable?